# FireFox Bookmark Deletion Problem

Tags: firefox

In windows I can easily delete a FF bookmark. To do so I just click on `Bookmarks` button. Then a list of bookmarks appears and I just right click on the bookmark which I want to delete and once a menu come with delete option I just click on this. Thats all. But in Ubuntu I see bookmark deletion is not that easy. If I open a list of bookmark and then right click on the bookmark browser actually takes me to the link as I did a left click! To delete a bookmark I just click on `Bookmarks`>`Show All Bookmarks`>`All bookmarks`>`Bookmarks menu` and then finally right click on the bookmark I want to delete and then click one the newly appeared delete menu. This sucks time. What is the easiest way to do so? Or I guess my mouse buttons are not properly setup?

Comment: might be the mouse, I can right click on mine:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/ALCrq.png

Comment: @Mateo Yes for me this is not happening. So this might be a ubuntu mouse issue. Can you tell me how can I solve the mouse button problem? And please reply as an answer so that I can chose your answer as the best and others will find this as useful too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably refering to using the bookmark menu from the "global menu".

I can confirm using the bookmar icon in the firefox toolbar, the bookmark sidebar and the bookmark manager works as you describe.